# Select first space in a String

Tags: xslt

I want to select first space of a string in a text.

Input :

```
<p>Text 1<italic>should</italic> Text 2.</p>
```

There is a space after `</italic>`. I want to select only that space and replace a `<s>` for that space. How can i do that.

Tried code :

```
<xsl:template match="p/text()[2]"> 
    <s/>
</xsl:template>
```

Expected results :

```
<p type="body">Text 1
   <style type="underline">should</style><s/>have surgery.</p>
```

This tried code not works properly. I am using xslt 2.0

Comment: **1.** Please show the expected result. **2.** Please indicate which version of XSLT your processor supports (do that for ALL your XSLT questions.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I have updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0, you could do:

```
<xsl:template match="p/text()[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::italic]]">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="^\s" >
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <s/>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

This matches the text node immediately following an `italic` element, and checks if the first character is a space. If it is, it will be replaced by an empty `s` element.

---

Alternatively, you could restrict the match pattern itself to include only nodes that start with a space:

```
<xsl:template match="p/text()[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::italic]][starts-with(., ' ')]">
    <s/>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 2)" />
</xsl:template>
```